# What parts of my answer in the question, "What are Madara Uchiha's weaknesses?" should be hidden with spoiler markup?

Tags: discussion, spoilers

What parts of [my answer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/3061/310) in the question, "[What are Madara Uchiha's weaknesses?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/76/what-are-madara-uchihas-weaknesses/)" should be hidden with spoiler markup?

I currently only hid the images I embedded in the answer with spoiler markup. Should I have hidden more or less of my answer with spoiler markup?

I answered the question with information from Chapters 622 and 623 (current latest chapter is 625). **Are info from chapters one to three issues earlier from the current one, considered spoilers by the community?**

Answer (score 1):

The answer is perfectly fine as is. You spoil no relevant plot points in what is not hidden, and hide only the images that constitute possible spoil material. Only those who know what's gonna be shown there or those who want to be spoiled will be spoiled by your answer.

Anyway, in a question like this, which is spoiler-ish by nature, you need not be so worried about that. If anyone feels the answer/question you post should be better laid out to prevent spoilers, that person will leave a comment or edit the post for you.

Answer (score 1):

We had a nasty habit spoilerififying practically anything that dates later than the current anime, dating back to the early days of private beta of this site.

We luckily managed to stop that habit (spoiler-marked content is not searchable, hard to find and hard to read). Only spoiler-mark things that would truly ruin someones view experience (A key character's death, identity revelations etc). Since we've already discussed Madara in that question, there's little spoilerify.

Comment: To add to this: If a title is a question whose answer is, in itself, a spoiler, the answer *likely* needs no spoiler tags at all, even though it is a spoiler by nature.